# Set DefaultFileSystemProvider for testing

Tags: java, nio, jimfs

How can I set the `DefaultFileSystemProvider` to use, for example, `JimfsFileSystemProvider`? The javadoc for [`FileSystems.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault()) says I need to set a system property, but when I try to do that I get a `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
System.setProperty("java.nio.file.spi.DefaultFileSystemProvider",
                   "com.google.common.jimfs.JimfsFileSystemProvider");
FileSystems.getDefault();
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.common.jimfs.JimfsFileSystemProvider.<init>(java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:128)
....
```

Do I need to set up something else or is this a bug in jimfs?

Comment: Needing to set the default file system is generally an anti-pattern, and intentionally not implemented by the Jimfs team.  See [Kevin Bourrillion's comment](https://plus.google.com/+googleguava/posts/a3idqfdnpzC) on Guava's Google+ post announcing Jimfs.

Comment: @dimo414 looks like a broken link

Comment: @Steve just tried it, it loads fine for me.

Comment: @dimo414 Really.....interesting. Maybe it's something with the proxy/firewall settings where I work. Sorry about that.

Comment: Kevin Bourrillion said: "We don't think that is the right way to go -- mutating global static state causes a huge mess. Instead, stop writing code that depends on the default file system. When code can accept a Path and work off its implicit fs, great; otherwise have the FileSystem itself injected.

(Also, stop writing code that depends on the system default anything! )"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc of [`FileSystems.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault--) states that:

> ...the default `FileSystemProvider` is instantiated by invoking a one argument constructor whose formal parameter type is `FileSystemProvider`.

Since `JimfsFileSystemProvider` does not have such constructor, you can't set it as the default file system.

This is exactly what the error means that you get:

```
java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.common.jimfs.JimfsFileSystemProvider.<init>(java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider)
```

The method `<init>` is the constructor, and no constructor found with parameters `java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider`.

Comment: I guess that's the correct answer. However, it would be nice if Jimfs would support that...